# Finding the nth smallest number in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

i need a efficient way of getting the nth smallest number AND its index in a list containing up to 15000 enties (so speed is not super crucial).

I sadly can't use numpy or any other non-standard library.

Im using Python 2.7

Comment: but sorting the list loses its original index

Comment: @mhlester: not if you use `sorted`

Answer (score 5):

use `heapq.nsmallest` (and `enumerate` to get the index):

```
nums = [random.randint(1,1000000) for _ in range(10000)]

import heapq
import operator

heapq.nsmallest(10,enumerate(nums),key=operator.itemgetter(1))
Out[26]: 
[(5544, 35),
 (1702, 43),
 (6547, 227),
 (1540, 253),
 (4919, 360),
 (7993, 445),
 (1608, 495),
 (5832, 505),
 (1388, 716),
 (5103, 814)]
```

Comment: For a list comprised of 10, 10, 10, 9, 8 - the 3rd smallest is arguably `8` and not `10`

Comment: It's possible I suppose but I'd consider that the less-intuitive interpretation.  If the OP needs de-duping, I'll address it.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to store the original position, then sort by the value:

```
original_list = [36, 44, 23, 24, 47, 19, 49, 36, 30, 3]
sorted_lookup = sorted(enumerate(original_list), key=lambda i:i[1])
position, value = sorted_lookup[4] # 4 is my "n"
```

sorted_lookup in my example is:

```
[(9, 3), (5, 19), (2, 23), (3, 24), (8, 30), (0, 36), (7, 36), (1, 44), (4, 47), (6, 49)]
```

And `position` is `8`, `value` is `30`